# The monotonicity of a weighted entropy

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, limits

Now we have $$p(x) = \frac{d!}{x!\,(d-x)!\,2^d}$$ $$e(x)=\frac{x}{d}\log\Bigg(\frac{d}{x}\Bigg) + \frac{d-x}{d}\log{\frac{d}{d-x}}$$ and $$E(d) = \sum_{0 < x < d}{p(x)e(x)}$$

How to prove the monotonicity of $E(d)$?